# How can I select all cells in table view in swift language

Tags: swift3, uitableview

I'm trying to load all cells in table view but I can't. I have received an error.
Did you have any solution to fix this issue?

This is my code :

```
func selectAllowCellInTableView(tableView:UITableView){
        for j in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections{
            for i in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: j){

                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: i, section: j)
                let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! VideoTableViewCell
                cell.imageViewCheck.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is the error which i receive it when i excute my code (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: each cell have the folder icon  with the label the table view only see the visible cells but the cells which is not visible display this error